# imgurpython.helpers.error.ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded

Tags: python, api, http, imgur, rate-limiting

I have the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 22, in <module>
    search = imgur_client.gallery_search('cat', window='all', sort='time', page=p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imgurpython/client.py", line 531, in gallery_search
    response = self.make_request('GET', 'gallery/search/%s/%s/%s' % (sort, window, page), data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imgurpython/client.py", line 153, in make_request
    raise ImgurClientRateLimitError()
imgurpython.helpers.error.ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded!
```

for this code:

```
  1 from imgurpython import ImgurClient
  2 import inspect
  3 import random
  4 import urllib2
  5 import requests
  6 from imgurpython.helpers.error import ImgurClientError
  7 
  8 client_id = "ABC"
  9 client_secret = "ABC"
 10 access_token = "ABC"
 11 refresh_token = "ABC"
 12 
 13 
 14 
 15 image_type = ['jpg', 'jpeg']
 16 
 17 imgur_client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret, access_token, refresh_token)
 18 
 19 item_count = 0
 20 for p in range(1, 10000):
 21     try:
 22         search = imgur_client.gallery_search('cat', window='all', sort='time', page=p)
 23         for i in range(0,https://gist.github.com/monajalal/e02792e9a5cbced301a8691b7a62836f len(search)):
 24             item_count +=1
 25             print(search[i].comment_count)
 26             if search[i].comment_count > 10 and not search[i].is_album:
 27                 print(search[i].type)
 28                 if search[i].type[6:] in image_type:
 29                     count = 0
 30                     try:
 31                         image_file = urllib2.urlopen(search[i].link, timeout = 5)
 32                         image_file_name = 'images/'+ search[i].id+'.'+search[i].type[6:]
 33                         output_image = open(image_file_name, 'wb')
 34                         output_image.write(image_file.read())
 35                         for post in imgur_client.gallery_item_comments(search[i].id, sort='best'):
 36                             if count <= 10:
 37                                 count += 1
 38                         output_image.close()
 39                     except urllib2.URLError as e:
 40                         print(e)
 41                         continue
 42                     except socket.timeout as e:
 43                         print(e)
 44                         continue
 45                     except socket.error as e:
 46                         print(e)
 47                         continue
 48     except ImgurClientError as e:
 49         print(e)
 50         continue
 51 
 52 print item_count
```

Also I see this line almost very often:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

How can I fix the error? Is there any workaround for rate limit error in Imgur? So I am creating this app for academic research use not for commercial and according to https://api.imgur.com/#limits it should be free but I had to register my app to get client_id related stuff. How can I set my application as non-commercial so that I would not get this rate limit error or if all kind of applications get this error how should I handle it? How should I set my code so that it would make only 1250 requests per hour?

Also here's my credit info:

```
User Limit: 500
User Remaining: 500
User Reset: 2016-10-18 14:32:41
User Client Limit: 12500
User Client Remaining: 9570
```

UPDATE: With sleep(8) as suggested in the answer I end up with this going on continuously. For different search query this happens at different pages. How can I fix the code so that it would stop executing when this happens? Here's the related code to the update: https://gist.github.com/monajalal/e02792e9a5cbced301a8691b7a62836f

```
page number is: 157
0
image/jpeg
page number is: 157
0
page number is: 157
0
page number is: 157
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Comment: Please ask a new question on SO about the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate limit refers to how frequently you're hitting the API, not how many calls you're allowed. To prevent hammering, most APIs have a rate limit (eg: 30 requests per minute, 1 every 2 seconds). Your script is making requests as quickly possible, hundreds or even thousands of times faster than the limit.

To prevent your script from hammering, the simplest solution is to introduce a [`sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) to your for loop.

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(10000):
    print i
    sleep(2) # seconds
```

Adjust the sleep time to be at least one second greater than what the API defines as its rate limit.

https://api.imgur.com/#limits

> The Imgur API uses a credit allocation system to ensure fair distribution of capacity. Each application can allow **approximately 1,250 uploads per day or approximately 12,500 requests per day**. If the daily limit is hit five times in a month, then the app will be blocked for the rest of the month. The remaining credit limit will be shown with each requests response in the `X-RateLimit-ClientRemaining` HTTP header.

So 12500 requests / 24 hours is 520 requests per hour or ~8 per minute. That means your sleep should be about 8 seconds long.

Comment: I know I can make only 1250 requests per hour but how much sleep would you estimate for this?

Comment: I am accepting the answer as it seems it is working for me with sleep(2). I will comment later if I saw the same error again! Thanks :)

Comment: if you got a chance please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116518/only-limited-number-of-pages-can-be-retrieved

Comment: @MonaJalal 12500 / 24 = 520 requests per hour. Updated my answer with a rough calculation of the rate limit.

Comment: 8 seconds is the minimum rate limit, set your sleep time to `sleep(8)`

Comment: please have a look at the UPDATE in the question and let me know if you might have any feedback?

Comment: @MonaJalal Please ask a new question on SO about the warning.